# Storing Result of SQL Query in RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Afternoon All,

I am attempting to call some Spark SQL on a SchemaRDD, and then the result stored in an RDD. The below line is producing the expected values, so I know the SQL is generating the correct table. Now I just need to store it.

```
sqlContext.sql("select encounter.Member_ID AS patientID, encounter.Encounter_DateTime AS date, diag.code from encounter join diag on encounter.Encounter_ID = diag.Encounter_ID").show(1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `sqlContext.sql` gives the `DataFrame`, you can call `.rdd()` to get
>   the `RDD[Row]` .

You can try this:

```
 val queryResult = sqlContext.sql("select encounter.Member_ID AS patientID, encounter.Encounter_DateTime AS date, diag.code from encounter join diag on encounter.Encounter_ID = diag.Encounter_ID")

 val rdd: RDD[Row] = queryResult.rdd
```

> Remove the `show` function on `DataFrame` since  *it displays the
>   content of the DataFrame to stdout*

Comment: Thanks for the response! Dropped the .show(1) at the end as well.

Comment: remove the .show() at the end. show method shows you some random rows from the dataframe

Comment: Got it to work for RDD[Row]. Now I am trying to match this table with the following class of RDD - `case class Diagnostic(patientID:String, date: Date, code: String)`. Attempting to build the RDD with `val res1: RDD[Diagnostic] = sqlContext.sql("select encounter.Member_ID AS patientID, encounter.Encounter_DateTime AS date, diag.code from encounter join diag on encounter.Encounter_ID = diag.Encounter_ID").rdd`

Comment: i m nt sure if it will match since queryResult.rdd returns you the RDD[Row]